# How to find various information about Fortran's commands?

Tags: fortran

I am starting to use Fortran on Mac. My question is simple, where can I find helps on various Fortran commands? I used to use MATLAB and whenever I don't understand how certain syntax works I can refer to its help menu however there is no such convenience in Fortran I think. Asking it on a forum like this one here everytime there is problem is clearly inefficient. I have also checked Fortran Company website but they do not seem to provide such information either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many online resources that have information in them, and cover different parts of the language at different levels.

I think [this page - Fortran 90/95 reference](http://www.icl.utk.edu/~mgates3/docs/fortran.html) is the most "reference guide" like. It appears to have been created by an academic and is hosted on the University of Tennessee

This [PDF - PGI Fortan Reference Guide](http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgifortref.pdf), available from the PG website is a rather large but very useful book covering most aspects of the language, which I have I refer to over and over.

Also, if you are stuck a specific thing, don't under estimate simply googling your problem. Chances are someone else has had the same problem and will have gone to the trouble of asking for you.

Comment: If you include the title of the site and documents, this post will be more robust about link changes. In general links are discouraged because they break, so to work around that try and use document titles in addition to the links.

Comment: Thank you very much the first link is certainly rich of information I will need. However, I am actually more interested in "search-and-click" type of help. For example if I want to find detailed information about variable declaration of type `real`, I would like to just type it in the search bar and click on the entry which specifically is devoted for `real` command. I wish I don't have to use Google search bar for this task simply because the resulting entry will be of diverse topic unless I put more restriction on the keyword.

Comment: I am also currently following a pdf guide obtained online. Here I learn that `real:: x` will declare `x` as a real variable. But in another article, there is an option `parameter` put after `real` separated by a comma which I don't know what it is for. It will be good if such help information devoted entirely for `real` statement is available. I am sorry if this sounds like I am forcing my behavior from Matlab to another language environment.

Comment: @nougako wouldn't searching for `parameter` be more appropriate if you want to know what `parameter` is/does -- the first link has a nice simple explanation. For the intrinsic routines you might find something like the gfortran intrinsic routines documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gfortran/Intrinsic-Procedures.html#Intrinsic-Procedures) closer to what you are after.

Comment: Well that problem with `parameter` was just for an example of what kind of problem I may encounter in the future. Anyway I think I have figured out that there is no one place where I can find the description of all Fortran statements along with their each options. Seems like scattered online sites is the best I can expect. By the way thanks for your link, that's the kind of thing I prefer although it's for routines.

Comment: Download something like the one here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-fortran-compiler-16.0-user-and-reference-guide-pdf there are also a few good books.

Comment: @Holmz, thanks a lot! That's what I have been looking for.